# Rails App fails to load webpack bundle

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, vue.js, webpack-dev-server

I'm having an issue setting up my fresh Rails/Vue app. When I launch webpack-dev-server, webpack compiles my JS succesfully. If I run my rails server and access it, the js bundle is loaded properly. When I make changes to my code, the webpack-dev-server recompiles my code and the website refreshes automatically. The new file, however, will occasionally fail to load.

I created the app using this command.

```
rails new vueapp --skip-turbolinks --webpack=vue
```

I've been unable to figure out how to reliably reproduce this failure, however I have determined from rails server log that the following text only shows up when my browser fails to locate the JS bundle:

```
[Webpacker] Compiling…
[Webpacker] Compiled all packs in C:/Users/Danny/Desktop/paperVue/public/packs
```

From the usual server message...

```
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-05-26 00:51:08 -0400
Processing by WelcomeController#index as HTML
  Rendering welcome/index.html.erb within layouts/application
[Webpacker] Compiling…
[Webpacker] Compiled all packs in C:/Users/Danny/Desktop/paperVue/public/packs
  Rendered welcome/index.html.erb within layouts/application (6765.6ms)
Completed 200 OK in 6859ms (Views: 6841.4ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

The message in my browser console is:

```
Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://localhost:3000/packs/hello_vue-1e8d683aa0d70cc071e0.js”.
```

I'm probably leaving out some vital information...

Comment: Maybe this [issue here](https://github.com/rails/webpacker/issues/1427) can help you

Comment: Did you solve it?